# Add ArrayList to another ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having the following java code, in which I am trying to copy the ArrayList to another ArrayList.

```java
ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList NodeList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < PropertyNode.getLength() - 1; i++) {
    Node childNode = PropertyNode.item(i);
    NodeList Children = childNode.getChildNodes();

    if (Children != null) {
        nodes.clear();
        nodes.add("PropertyStart");
        nodes.add(Children.item(3).getTextContent());
        nodes.add(Children.item(7).getTextContent());
        nodes.add(Children.item(9).getTextContent());
        nodes.add(Children.item(11).getTextContent());
        nodes.add(Children.item(13).getTextContent());
        nodes.add("PropertyEnd");
    }
    NodeList.addAll(nodes);
    list.add(NodeList);
}
```

I want the "list" array to be in this format:

```
[[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd],[PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd],[PropertyStart,......]]
```

But from the above code, the "list" array output is seen like this:

```
[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,....PropertyEnd]
```

I think you might have noticed the difference. I am not able to achieve the result in expected format.

Comment: Don't use raw lists. Use the generic types, and you'll see the problem...

Comment: Please start your variable names with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @Keppil, Thanks for your suggestion. I will correct myself here onwards.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Then you need a `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
nodes.add(nodeList);
```

Note that `NodeList` has been changed to `nodeList`. In [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) variables start with a lower case. Classes start with an upper case.

Answer (score 15):

## Your Problem

Mainly, you've got 2 major problems:

You are using adding a `List` of `String`s. You want a `List` containing `List`s of `Strings`.

Note as well that when you invoke this:

```
NodeList.addAll(nodes);
```

... all you say is to add all elements of nodes (which is a list of Strings) to the (badly named) `NodeList`, which is using Objects and thus adds only the strings inside. Which leads me to the next point.

You seem to be confused between your `nodes` and `NodeList`. Your `NodeList` keeps growing over time, and that's what you add to your list.

So, even if doing things right, if we were to look at the end of each iteration at your `nodes`, `nodeList` and `list`, we'd see:

- *i = 0*

  ```
  nodes: [PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd]
  nodeList: [PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd]
  list: [[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd]]
  ```
- *i = 1*

  ```
  nodes: [PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd]
  nodeList: [PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd, PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd]
  list: [[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd],[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd, PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd]]
  ```
- *i = 2*

  ```
  nodes: [PropertyStart,g,h,i,PropertyEnd]
  nodeList: [PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,g,h,i,PropertyEnd]
  list: [[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd],[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd, PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd],[PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,g,h,i,PropertyEnd]]
  ```
- *and so on...*

### Some Other Corrections

#### Follow the Java Naming Conventions

Don't use variable names starting with uppercase letters. So here, replace `NodeList` with `nodeList`).

#### Learn a Bit More About Types

You say "I want the "list" array [...]". This is confusing for whoever you will be communicating with: It's not an array. It's an implementation of `List` backed by an array.

There's a difference between a type, an interface, and an implementation.

#### Use Generics for Stronger Typing in Collections

Use generic types, because static typing really helps with these errors. Also, use interfaces where possible, except if you have a good reason to use the concrete type.

So your code becomes:

```
List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

#### Remove Unnecessary Code

You could do away with the `nodeList` entirely, and write the following once you've fixed your types:

```
list.add(nodes);
```

#### Use the Right Scope

Except if you have a very strong reason to do so, prefer to use the inner-most scope to declare variables and limit both their lifespan for their references and facilitate the separation of concerns in your code.

Here you could then move `List<String> nodes` to be declared within the loop (and then forget the `nodes.clear()` invocation).

<sub>A reason not to do this could be performance, as you might want to avoid recreating an `ArrayList` on each iteration of the loop, but it's very unlikely that's a concern to you (and *clean, readable and maintainable code has priority over pre-optimized code*).</sub>

## [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Last but not least, if you want help give us the exact reproducible case with a [short, self-Contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Here you give us your program's outputs, but don't mention how you got them, so we're left to assume you did a `System.out.println(list)`. And you confused a lot of people, as I think the output you give us is not what you actually got.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it just be a case of:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Fill in nodeList here...

outer.add(nodeList);
```

Repeat as necesary.

This should return you a list in the format you specified.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is caused that you use the same ArrayList **NodeList** over all iterations in main for loop. Each iterations **NodeList** is enlarged by new elements.

1. After first loop, **NodeList** has 5 elements (PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd) and **list** has 1 element (NodeList: (PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd))
2. After second loop **NodeList** has 10 elements (PropertyStart,a,b,c,PropertyEnd,PropertyStart,d,e,f,PropertyEnd) and **list** has 2 elements (NodeList (with 10 elements), NodeList (with 10 elements))

To get you expectations you must replace

```
NodeList.addAll(nodes);
list.add(NodeList)
```

by

```
List childrenList = new ArrayList(nodes);
list.add(childrenList);
```

PS. Your code is not readable, keep Java code conventions to have readble code. For example is hard to recognize if NodeList is a class or object

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the NodeList inside the for loop and you will get the desired output.

```
ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<PropertyNode.getLength()-1;i++){
            ArrayList NodeList=new ArrayList();
            Node childNode =  PropertyNode.item(i);
                NodeList Children = childNode.getChildNodes();

                if(Children!=null){
                    nodes.clear();
                    nodes.add("PropertyStart");
                    nodes.add(Children.item(3).getTextContent());
                    nodes.add(Children.item(7).getTextContent());
                    nodes.add(Children.item(9).getTextContent());
                    nodes.add(Children.item(11).getTextContent());
                    nodes.add(Children.item(13).getTextContent());
                    nodes.add("PropertyEnd");

                }   
                NodeList.addAll(nodes);
                list.add(NodeList);
        }
```

Explanation:
NodeList is an object which remains same throughout the loop so adding same variable to list in a loop will actually add it only once. The loop is only adding its variables in single NodeList array hence you must be seeing

```
[/*list*/    [  /*NodeList*/   ]   ]
```

and NodeList contains [prostart, a,b,c,proend,prostart,d,e,f,proend ...]

Answer (score 0):

Very first will declare outer Arraylist which will contain another inner Arraylist inside it

ArrayList> CompletesystemStatusArrayList;
ArrayList systemStatusArrayList

CompletesystemStatusArrayList=new ArrayList

systemStatusArrayList=new ArrayList();

```
    systemStatusArrayList.add("1");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("2");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("3");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("4");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("5");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("6");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("7");
    systemStatusArrayList.add("8");

    CompletesystemStatusArrayList.add(systemStatusArrayList);
```